# Why does a Func<T,bool> work with RavenDB query if I have 4k documents, but not when I have 800k documents?

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

If I have 4 thousand documents (maybe quite a few more, haven't checked) I can use a `Func<T,bool>` in `IDocumentSession.Query<T>().Where(...)` and I get the expected results. But if I have 800 thousand documents then I have to use an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, otherwise I get no results.

Why is this not consistent?

The issue is that I have the same predicate used for an in-memory filter as well as a database query filter. For the in-memory filter the collection is `IEnumerable<T>` so it uses a `Func<T,bool>` whereas for the database query the collection is an `IQueryable<T>` so it uses an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`. So in my production code I have an overloaded "filter" method - one that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and another that takes an `IQueryable<T>`. Content of the former is: `return list.Where(getPredicate(x).Compile())` and content of the latter is: `return list.Where(getPredicate(x))`

Obviously this just looks like duplicated code and is shouting out: "Please refactor me and reduce the code duplication". But as soon as a developer does that it should break a unit test. However, I can't get a unit test to fail when passing a `Func<T,bool>`.

**Edit:** Upon closer inspection, it appears that it has nothing to do with the number of documents. If I connect to the same "production" database in my unit test (calling the actual production code), it returns results when using `Func<T,bool>` but when I run the application it returns nothing. Very strange!

Comment: I never used RavenDB, but if you use `Func<T,bool>` I am quite sure it would retrieve all data and run through it at client side.

Comment: I understand that. What I want to do is write a unit test which breaks if a developer changes it from an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to a `Func<T,bool>`. But whatever I do, the unit test still passes, because the test data doesn't have as many documents as the production data.

Comment: @Shayne well, if the developers change these kind of things without knowing the difference... Change the developers !

Comment: Or teach them why they are wrong and how to improve. Developers not objects to be thrown away when they make a mistake. Objects cannot learn, humans can.

Comment: @Sean Frankly, I can't afford developers making mistakes. That's why I have unit tests. If I can't write a unit test which guarantees that my code will work in production then what is the point of unit testing at all?

Comment: Well that's fair enough, I personally don't like the stance that you just replace people if they make a mistake. Several, after being warned and whatnot, then yes. I also understand that businesses have to look after their cash flow. I just don't think it's helpful to offer that as advice in any situation. I do happen to agree with you on the unit test aspect though, if you don't have 100% test coverage you might as well have not bothered in the first place. How about writing to a log if the incoming type is wrong and then checking that log for this specific entry and then failing the test?

Comment: ... Instead of throwing an exception if you really don't want to throw an exception.

Comment: You could use reflection in your unit test, to `Assert` that the types match...

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's a very bad idea to use a `Func<T, bool>` when working with `IQueryable`, because this mean you will retrieve all elements from db (because your Queryable will be enumerated), then the filter will be applied on then `IEnumerable<T>`.

If you work with an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, the Where clause will be applied on the db level, and only the filtered elements will be retrieved.

**Edit**:
The behaviour is perfectly "correct", and absolutely predictable.

These 2 `Where` are 2 extension methods.

The one with `Func` takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as argument. And `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`. So if you use a `Func` as argument, this method will be taken, and the `Queryable` will be enumerated before filtering.

Comment: So why not throw an exception when passing a Func<T,bool>? This behaviour is unpredictable because it works for small sets of data, but not for large sets.

Comment: I would say the behaviour is 100% predictable. When you use a `Func<T, bool>` parameter you are using the `Enumerable.Where` extension method. When you use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` you are using the `Queryable.Where` extension method. It could be easy to use a wrong one, but that doesn't make it unpredictable.

Comment: @Lukazoid I know that, but the issue is that I have the same predicate used for an in-memory filter as well as a database query filter. For the in-memory filter the collection is `IEnumerable<T>` so it uses a `Func<T,bool>` whereas for the database query the collection is an `IQueryable<T>` so it uses an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`. So in my production code I have an overloaded "filter" method - one that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and another that takes an `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`. Content is:
`return list.Where(getPredicate(x).Compile())` and
`return list.Where(getPredicate(x))`